# Select 2 functionality issue in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am using select2 within my tool and using it within a modal.

[image]

The plugin isn't working in IE correctly (in the modal) but works fine on the normal page.

I had an issue with it before where the drop down appeared behind the window and fixed it with this code:`<style type="text/css">
    .modal .modal-body {
        max-height: 420px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>`

When I inspect the field I am typing into on both FF and IE, its the same field:

```
FF : <input class="select2-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">


IE:<input class="select2-input select2-focused" type="text"     jQuery111006508689540941444="114" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Any ideas on whats happening? No js errors that I can see

Comment: IE is a pain in the ass

Comment: I know, just happens to be the browser we use internally at work which is what the tool needs to be compatible with :/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Could you please elaborate? What exactly isn't working about it?

Comment: That will be hard to tell what the problem is without any demo

Comment: When the select2 is in the modal, it doesn't allow you to type in the field on IE but firefox works just fine. I'm guessing the field is behind the modal and isnt allowing anything to be entered.

Comment: So you are saying this is a common `z-index` issue ?

Comment: Any chance you've tried using Modernizr or any other JS scripts that help IE work right?

Comment: Check out these links for some possible solutions to the problem https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/942 and https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/600

Comment: Here is a Fiddle of what isnt working in IE for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/HQ64s/  When clicking the button and the modal fires, it doesn't allow me to type in the field on IE; I can type but nothing happens

Comment: what IE version are you using ? No issue for me under IE11. Are you saying that the fiddle **does** work for you but not your website ?

Comment: Needs to support IE8 as its for an internal site for company I work for and that is what is used.

Comment: quit your company immediatly before it is too late... I will take a look. But it does not surprise me that there are issues with twitter bootstrap / jquery and select2 plugin under IE8

Comment: It actually works under IE8

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont just use this plugin??
Its seems to be compatible with ff and ie too

https://github.com/alxlit/bootstrap-chosen

or this

https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select